# Does this mathematical technique have a formal name? And why does it work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, problem-solving

When I split a number in the powers of 2. I am able to make any combination of any number that is less than it by taking each number of the series only once.

For example:

$7=1+2+4$

I can construct any number less than or equal to seven using the $3$ numbers $1,2,4$.

Or take $10$ for instance:

$10 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 3$

I can construct any number that is less than or equal to $10$ using the 4 numbers.

How this decomposition is done is via **breaking the number in powers of 2 until you can't break it anymore.** More examples:

```
5 -> (1, 2, 2)
10 -> (1, 2, 4, 3)
15 -> (1, 2, 4, 8)
1000 -> (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 489)
```

Does this method of decomposition have a name? And how does it allow us to make any number that is less than or equal to it?

Comment: How is $3$ a power of $2$? Or $489$? You could write $10=2+8$ and $1000=512+256+128+64+32+8$, these are the [binary representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation) of the numbers.

Comment: @Servaes When you are unable to break the remainder anymore into a power of 2 you just leave the remainder as it is and end the process.

Comment: @Servaes Break the number as $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 \dots + remainder$ Did you get it ?

Comment: @ng.newbie No, I don't get it. Why would you use $10=1+2+\color{red}3\color{black}+4$ instead of $10=2+8$

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Why is $5=(1,2,2)$ instead of $(1,4)$?  The rules seem arbitrary.

Comment: You say “using each number only once” but your decomposition of $5$ has two $2$’s in it.

Comment: @RushabhMehta $10 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 3$. I have edited the question. I put the numbers in ascending order. Maybe that's why you were confused. Did you get it now?

Comment: @ng.newbie Nope, you don't ever need a remainder, so why do you have one. Why not 10 = 2+8

Comment: I think you guys are missing that it’s *increasing* powers of $2$. So you go $1+2+4+8+...$ until the next power of 2 is too large.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you subtract the powers of $2$ in ascending order, starting at $2^0=1$, until this is no longer possible (in the natural numbers). The remainder is the last number in the representation.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Ahhh I see, that's ... odd

Comment: @StellaBiderman Powers in ascending order starting from 0. 5 has two 2s in it becuase after the first 2, it cannot be broken as the next power of 2.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Yes it is odd. Does this have a name?

Comment: @ng.newbie nope, not really, because I've never seen any practical use for this

Comment: oh okay, so the remainder is allowed to be a repeat. It’s just that when going up the list of powers of two initially (before the remainder) you only get each number once.

Comment: Do we call this "binary"?

Comment: **Congratulations,** you've rediscovered binary numbers!  That's very well done.  The fact that they've been written about before shouldn't lessen your pride of discovery.  Best wishes for your future success playing with mathematics.  :)

Comment: No these are not binary numbers at all, because you split from the "wrong end". You need to start splitting from the largest power of 2 for them to be binary numbers.

Comment: This is the basis of "place notation", eg binary (here) & decimal & arbitrary base notations. PS It would be helpful for understanding & reasoning & clarity of asking & for finding answers on your own if you clearly precisely expressed in sentences what you mean by "split a number in the powers of 2" & "this decomposition". Ie what is your "example" an example *of*?

Comment: Can anyone suggest a better title for this question now?

Comment: @philipxy Got this method when I was reading about the bounded knapsack problem being turned into a 0/1 Knapsack problem. It was from this [paper](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter3.pdf).

Comment: I am not sure what the point of your last comment is--why are you stating this fact? Note that the point of my last comment was that if you do not make the effort to be clear then you will not get the benefits--*your* understanding & reasoning & being understood & learning.

Comment: @philipxy Yes I have already mentioned that in the question itself. I want to know one if this has a formal name, so maybe I can track down its proof. And I still don't understand completely why all the numbers can be formed by addition of all the previous powers of 2. What am I missing in my question according to you?

Answer (score 10):

To see that you can write every natural number $≤n$ as a partial sum of the decomposition of $n$:

Let $2^k$ be the greatest power of $2$ not exceeding $n$.  Then your decomposition is $$n=1+2+\cdots +2^{k-1}+ (n-2^k+1)$$

That is, the "remainder" is $r_n=n-2^k+1$.

We note that $1+2+\cdots +2^{k-1}=2^k-1$ so you can get every natural number $<2^k$ as a partial sum of those terms (using the binary expansion).

But then, adding $r_n$ you get can every natural number from $r_n$ to $r_n+2^k-1=n$ and we are done.

Comment: You seem to have an off-by-one error. $1+2=4-1$

Comment: @StellaBiderman  Yes, thanks.   I specialize in those.  Here the blunder was that $1+2+\cdots +2^{k-1}=2^k-1$, not $2^k$.

Comment: @lulu No, I don't quite understand it yet. Why can't I form all numbers from an expansion of the powers of $3$ or $4$ or $5$ or any other number? The power of $1$ and $2$ are the only ones that have this property. That was my question. Is this the correct place or clarify it or should I post a different thread?

Comment: @lulu When you say "so you can get every natural number $<2^k$ as a partial sum of those terms (using the binary expansion)" I dont understand what you mean by this. What exactly is binary expansion?

Comment: "Binary Expansion", just refers to writing integers in base $2$.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) for a standard write up. You only need the digits $0$ and $1$, so any integer can be written as a sum of distinct terms in $\{1,2,2^2,2^3,\cdots\}$.  You can write every integer in base $3$ or $5$ but you need digits other than $0$ and $1$.  That means you can't write every integer as a sum of distinct terms in $\{1,3,3^2,\cdots\}$.

Comment: @lulu Okay tell me what is so special about the powers of 2? If I use the same rules, but just try to use the powers of 10. I am unable to form any number. For example: $516 = 1 + 10 + 100 + 405$. I cant form the number 27 with the decomposed powers of 10. So whats special about 2?

Comment: @ng.newbie "That was my question." *What* is your question? *What* "rules"? Read your post. It isn't clear. You don't explain "decompose". "breaking the number in powers of 2 until you can't break it anymore" is vague. "make any combination of any number that is less than it by taking each number of the series only once" is unintelligible. It doesn't mention powers other than 2. "I cant form the number 27 with the decomposed powers of 10."--?? Guessing from all your examples & unclear text, that is wrong, since 27=1+10+16. Please edit your post to say exactly what you mean by "decompose".

Comment: The only special thing about $2$ is that the only necessary multipliers are $0$ and $1$.  If you use base $3$ you need $0,1,2$.  If you use base $10$ you need $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.  In general, if $b$ is a natural number, then base $b$ requires $b$ digits ($0,1,\cdots, b-1$)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, $1+2+4+\cdots2^n = 2^{n+1}-1$. So, for example

$$1000 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256 + \color{red}{489}$$
$$1000 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^8 + \color{red}{489}$$
is the same thing as saying $$1000 = (512-1)+\color{red}{489}$$
$$1000 = (2^9-1)+\color{red}{489}$$

If you pick a number, say $2345$, you notice that 
$$2^{11}-1 = 2047 < 2345 < 2^{12}-1=4095$$

and

$$2345-2047 = 298$$

So

$$2345 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + \cdots + 2048 + \color{red}{298}$$

I have never seen anything mathematical that referred to this pattern. So I don't know if it has a name or not, nor can I know if anyone else found it interesting.

Comment: The last power of two in the last equality should be $1024$, not $2048$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a process of breaking a number into a sum of powers of $2$, called the [binary expansion](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiGuYqjifTcAhXyyYUKHeqFDaAQFjACegQICxAK&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBinary_number&usg=AOvVaw0tfR_vFMRB5uUQDMoIaWDK). To do this, you first see what is the **largest** power of $2$ that is smaller than your number. Then you take it out, and iterate.

This is different from your own process, because what you do is take powers of $2$ **from the smallest** ($1$) and keep going till the next larger doesn't fit. However, the usual binary expansion is quite useful, as shown for instance by the example below.

Using it to compute powers efficiently in time is called the fast exponentiation algorithm, or [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#2k-ary_method). E.g. to compute $x^7$ all you need is $x$, squared into $x^2$ squared into $x^4$ and multiply all three $$x^7=x\cdot x^2\cdot x^4$$

Comment: But the issue is that his expansion is not exactly binary, e.g. $10=1+2+\color{red}3\color{black}+4$

Comment: -1 The comments make clear that this is not what the asker is after.

Comment: @Servaes Possibly. I edited to explain the difference between the OP and this answer, because it is quite straightforward to explain.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Wonder why this got a downvote

Comment: @ng.newbie Thanks. Servaes explained that I was not really answering the question. I guess it's debatable.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this method does not have a name. Perhaps if you could describe its purpose, or give some context, that would help to find a name.

And it is obvious from the definition that every number can be represented this way; given a number $n$, you keep subtracting higher powers of $2$ the remainder is less than the next power of $2$. The remainder is then the last number in the representation.

Comment: It really comes down to the flexibility of the remainder +1.

Comment: @Servaes Got this method when I was reading about the bounded knapsack problem being turned into a 0/1 Knapsack problem. It was from this [paper](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter3.pdf).

Comment: Since it is clearly not obvious to the OP why this occurs, I think more of an explanation is required.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Yes I need more explanation. More than I want to know how I can combine it to make any number less than or equal to that number I am breaking.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Feel free to give one; I can't be bothered to explain why division with remainder is well-defined at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Countrary to most of your feedback, this is not at all binary representation, because you split from the small end and not from the big end.

For binary representation to represent 7 you start with:

1. 8 no it's too big
2. 4, ok it fits, 7-4=3 left,
3. 2, ok it fits 3-2=1 left
4. 1, ok it fits 1-1=0 left, done!

What you are doing is splitting from the small end, so you will end up with a number $2^k-1 + b$, where $b$ is some remainder. I don't know if this has any name, but it sure is not a binary representation of the number.

Comment: This is essentially a copy of my answer. In fact, I don't think that you have read the other answers at all, because none of them assumes that the OP was talking about binary representation.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier it turns out you are right. I wrote answer early, but then lost internet connection for like 8 hours and then when I posted apparently several other answers had come in.