# What is a binary expansion of a real number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, binary

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885700/does-this-mathematical-technique-have-a-formal-name-and-why-does-it-work) I asked.

I want to know what is exactly meant by a binary expansion of a number, real or natural.

Can someone show me via example, how would you binary expand a real number like 1.575? And can someone show me how 535 would be broken up?

My next question is why does this work? Why do binary expansions work? Why can't I get the same thing out of a power of 3 or 4 or 5 for that matter?

Why does powers of 2 work?

Comment: Of course there are base 3, 4, or 5 expansions.

Comment: @MartinR You mean I can get any number expanded in the base of 3 or 4? What about 2? How can I get 2 from an expansion of 3 or 4? This is really confusing

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me). Perhaps this: A "base-b" expansion ($b \ge 2$) is a sum of powers of $b$, multiplied with “digits” in the range $0..b-1$. As an example, the base-2 expansion of $11$ is $2^3 + 2^1 + 2^0$, and the base-3 expansion of $11$ is $3^2 + 2 \cdot 3^0$. – Base 2 is only “special” in the sense that digits are only zero or one, so every integer can be written as a sum of (different) powers of 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For any base $b\geq 2$ (of course, $b\in\mathbb N$) and any real number $x$, you can write the number in base $b$ as

$$x = a_na_{n-1}\dots a_0.b_1b_2b_3\dots$$

where this means that $$x=a_0 + a_1\cdot b + a_2\cdot b^2 + \cdots + a_nb^n + b_1b^{-1} + b_2b^{-2} + \cdots$$ and all numbers $a_i$ and $b_i$ are elements of $\{0,1,\dots, b-1\}$

this can be done no matter what number $b$ you choose as the base. For example, in base $10$, the number $16$ is written as $16$ because $16=1\cdot 10 + 6\cdot 10^{0}$. In base $2$, the number is written as $10000$, because $$16=0\cdot 2^0 + 0\cdot 2^1 + 0\cdot 2^2 + 0\cdot 2^3 + 1\cdot 2^4.$$

---

This is also true for numbers that are not integers, for example, in base $10$, you write $\frac14$ as $0.25$ because $$\frac14 = 2\cdot 10^{-1} + 5\cdot 10^{-2}$$ while in base $2$, it's written as $0.01$ because $$\frac14 = 0\cdot 2^{-1} + 1\cdot 2^{-2}.$$

However, for non-integers, the expansions can sometimes be (more like usually is:) infinite. For example, the number $\frac13$ is written as $0.3333333\dots$ in base $10$, but in base $3$, it's simply $0.1$.

---

Naturally, for bases higher than $10$, we don't have enough symbols to write all the numbers, but we can make more up. For example, the base $16$ system uses the letters $a,b,c,d,e,f$ to represent the numbers $10,11,12,13,14,15$, meaning that $31$ in base $16$ is written as $$1f$$ because $$31 =1\cdot 16 + f\cdot 16^0.$$
Similarly, in that base, $$\frac{14}{16} = 0.e$$

Comment: Can you show me the break up of 16 in base 5?

Comment: @ng.newbie sure. $15=3\cdot 5^1 +1\cdot5^0$ so in base $5$, the number $15$ is written as $31$

Comment: Okay so I have to get the representation of that number in that particular base then I can convert it. For example I first have to get the binary representation of 16 before I can expand it in base 2. Correct?

Comment: Really good and clear answer. Just for a bit of nitpicking: in your first exemple, I think it would have been clearer if you wrote the power of 2 in decreasing order, so the 10000 clearly shows himself

Comment: @ng.newbie What's the difference from a binary representation and an expansion in that base?

Comment: @5xum I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @ng.newbie I don't understand what you mean by "get the binary representation of 16 before I can expand it in base 2". What's the difference in your mind between the first and the second? Writing a number in base $2$ is, to me, the exact same thing as finding the base $2$ (also called binary) representation of that number

Comment: @5xum Yes I mean you can't expand 16 in decimal to $2^4$. Decimal expansion would be $10*1 + 6*1$.

Comment: @ng.newbie Sorry, but I have no idea what you are talking about right now.

Comment: @5xum Sorry I think I messed up. Just tell me something if I want to convert $24$ to base 5 I have to do the following = $4*5^1 + 4 * 5^0 = 44$ in base 5. Am I correct?

Comment: @ng.newbie Well if you want to convert $x$ to base $5$ you have to calculate the values $a_0,\dots, a_n$ such that $a_0 + 5a_1 + \cdots + 5^na_n=x$. For $x=24$ (in decimal), the values turn out to be $a_0=a_1=4$.

Comment: @5xum Okay I think I get it now. Will ask you further questions as they pop up in my mind.

Comment: @ng.newbie Good luck!